# How do connect to MySQL via IP, not just localhost

Tags: mysql, wamp

I would like to make my home WAMP server's MySQL instance be exposed to the internet for updates from an external source. I am able to use MySQL Workbench and connect locally (on same box) with localhost or 127.0.0.1. If I use the boxes IP, I can't connect. I'm sure this is a simple security configuration change, just now sure where.

My desire is to port forward 3306 on my router to this box.

What settings need changing?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are using the computer's IP address, it is no longer considered part of the loopback (localhost or 127.0.0.1). Instead it is routed and acts as an external local connection. You will need to edit your mysql.ini (or whatever configuration file) and comment out the `BIND 127.0.0.1` or `BIND localhost` line. Restart your MySQL server and it should allow incoming requests from external sources (including the same computer through the nonroutable IP address).

Comment: Turns out that I didn't need to make any changes to the default MySQL setup. The issue is that "root" doesn't work for remote connections. I needed to add another MySQL user which was not restricted to an IP (or I could've restricted the IP)... Once I did that, I was able to connect with no issue.

Comment: Commenting it out did work for me. The new version of mysql calls the line "bind-address = 127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know that I had the same issue, once I created a new user and connected with it instead of root, I was finally able to access from the IP address instead of localhost.
I didn't even have to change the my.ini file.